# Images are uploaded but those are not avaliable in a form

Tags: webforms

I have a problem with webform module and that too with my site only :(
When I add form field with image upload, photos are uploaded but when I check submissions there are empty places, only I can find this photo in FTP in path sites/all/webform/

When I add required field, so user can not go to the next page break
I choose file, format and weight is correct, I click upload a file, looks that is uploaded

[image]

I try to go to the next page break but it is impossible because appears a notice that this field is required and is empty...

[image]

I try to do in another webform created, without page breaks and another fields, but issue is the same.

In another drupal site in my server I don't have this issue. If you want to reproduce please go to my site:
[vidicon.nazwa.pl/brodnica/zgloszenie_firmy](http://vidicon.nazwa.pl/brodnica/zgloszenie_firmy)

please fill fields with* and after upload photo in last field and try to go to next step. It will be not possible but I will have this image on my server in /sites/default/files/webform/...

BTW I try to create a another simple form with image upload field and the same issue occurs, permission I set the same as in other site where webform works properly. I don't have any ideas, but I need this webform to my site :(

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Does the issue persist outside Webform content type?

Comment: only around webform :/ in custom content type with image field - add image is correct

Comment: It is hard if there is no error message. I just tried this in my local server. Drupal 7.43 + webform  7.x-4.12. Everything works fine. I suspect there is something with your server or installation but I'm not sure.

Comment: So then I know :) but what is wrong? I just tested in other installation and works, but I need this instalation... and that something going wrong :/

Comment: And errors in the Drupal watchdog logs or in your webserver logs?

Comment: From server errors only I have this:
[Mon Jun 06 16:04:40.557727 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 124:tid 4111895440] [client 213.17.170.58:55540] AH01071: Got error 'Passing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'magic_quotes_gpc'\nPassing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'magic_quotes_sybase'\nPassing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'register_globals'\n', referer: http://vidicon.nazwa.pl/brodnica/zgloszenie_firmy

Comment: and this:[Mon Jun 06 16:04:42.740146 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 124:tid 4044753808] [client 213.17.170.58:55540] AH01071: Got error 'Passing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'magic_quotes_gpc'\nPassing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'magic_quotes_sybase'\nPassing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'register_globals'\n', referer: http://vidicon.nazwa.pl/brodnica/zgloszenie_firmy

Comment: From drupal logs - nothing related to this problem :(

Comment: any ideas to resolve this :(( ? I don;t have any ideas and my webportal waiting to start :/

Answer (score 2):

Case is resolved, issue appears in drupal 7.43 and 7.44, I last version - 7.50 works ok

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81820)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer he is the author `:p`

Comment: @NoSssweat But do you think that the answer it's good. Or is better improve the answer?

Comment: as you can see there was no helpfull answers, in last drupal release works ok, so why the answer is not good for you???